# Collision system not working. There are no errors, it just wont register that the projectile hit the player

Tags: unity-game-engine

Here is the code in which I was talking about. I can't figure out why my collider isn't working:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject obj;
    void Awake ()
    {
        obj = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
            {
              obj.GetComponent<Health>().health -= 25;
            }
        }
      
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the code you have, make sure to change some code. This is what you should change: get rid of the obj variable and the awake function. Then instead of finding the object with that name, use tag. Also get rid of `Update(){}` and take the `OnCollisionEnter(){}` out of it.
A few more changes are shown in code:

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
 var obj = collision.GameObject;
  if (obj.Tag == “Player”){
  obj.GetComponent<Health>().health -= 25;
  }
}
```

This will work as long as: the script is called `Health`, the variable inside `Health` is called `health`, and it is set to a float, and the player’s tag is set to `Player`.

Comment: Ken, I am getting this error: 'Collision' does not contain a definition for 'GameObject' and no accessible extension method 'GameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Collision' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use a lowercase g; collision.gameObject

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code pasted in the question is just copied over wrong, but `OnCollisionEnter()` is its own unique method and should not be nested in `Update()`.

If the player will be colliding with this Sphere object often, it is good to cache a component rather than using `GetComponent` frequently. However I assume in your case this Sphere will be one of many obstacles, so calling the `GetComponent` in the collision is fine. The issue with your current code is the gameObject you are colliding with might not have the name exactly spelled as `Player`, which would make your collision check fail. Caching the object that has the tag of Player is a bit redundant when you can just check it inside of the collision check.

I will use your entire snippet of code so there is no confusion

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        // compare if the collider's gameObjects tag is equal to our target tag (Player)
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            // get the component of Health on our gameObject that we collided with that has the tag of Player
            obj.GetComponent<Health>().health -= 25;
        }
    }
}
```